# Падает сайт на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cms

Когда я пытаюсь установить плагин CF7, то у меня почему-то сайт всё время падает? Почему так? Мне кажется это из за установленной темы, такое возможно?

Comment: А версия Wordpress совместима с плагином?

Comment: написано, что тестов не было. то есть неизвестно

Comment: Что значит "падает"?  На каком этапе? Логи что говорят?

Comment: [16-Feb-2017 15:50:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare tgmpa_load_bulk_installer() (previously declared in /home/s/sashkai0/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cf7-customizer.old/assets/admin/inc/tgm/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php:2931) in /home/s/sashkai0/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/class-tgm-plugin-activation.php on line 3378

Comment: ошибка 500 при попытке загрузке сайта http://sashkai0.bget.ru/?v=f9308c5d0596

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare tgmpa_load_bulk_installer() (previously declared in /home/s/sashkai0/site/public_html/wp-content/plugins/cf7-cus‌​tomizer.old/assets/a‌​dmin/inc/tgm/class-t‌​gm-plugin-activation‌​.php:2931) in /home/s/sashkai0/site/public_html/wp-content/themes/zerif-li‌​te/class-tgm-plugin-‌​activation.php on line 3378`

`cf7-cus‌​tomizer.old` - это что за мусор? Удалить и поставить нормально плагин. [CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)

Тему обновить с [оф сайта](https://themeisle.com/themes/zerif-lite/). В репо её нет.

Comment: а как можно самому поднять сайт?

Comment: Я ж написал - прежде всего удалить каталог cf7-cus‌​tomizer.old и обновить тему. После этого установить НУЖНЫЙ плагин, а не дополнение к нему. Я ж и ссылки все дал.

Comment: да просто другая проблема была